# Why I can't read BoxSync.Core.Doc.chm?

Tags: box-api

everyone, I downloaded the file named "BoxSync.Core.Doc.chm" from the link: https://code.google.com/p/boxsyncnet/downloads/detail?name=BoxSync.Core.Doc.chm&can=2&q=

It's strange, why I can't read it?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that may be an old C# SDK that is no longer maintained.  You may want to look at the SDK's that Box has on it's developers pages:  https://developers.box.com/sdks/